# Write failed MAKE commands into a file

Tags: make

I am running `make -j -k`. I want to write the exact commands that **fail** into a file. The output should not be scrambled because of `-j`.

Comment: `make -k 2>&1 | tee file.log` -- i.e. omit the `-j` option?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Not **inifite**! `With no argument, make runs as many recipes simultaneously as possible.` https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I have a very huge output of make, which runs in parallel. I want to get only failed commands. Make already knows the failures so I want to extract that info directly from the make program.

Comment: You could try `SunPro Make` instead, as it collects output from the various jobs and emmits them in a serial way. `SunPro Make` is part of the schilytools and available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/